# aireplay-ng command not found

Tags: linux, path, command, admin, root

I just downloaded and installed Kali Linux on my MacBook Pro (dual boot) to mess around with penetration testing - I have experience with aircrack-ng, but it was a while ago (and I was at least unaware of the distributions geared towards penetration testing). Finally got everything up and running, and customized the way I want - I tried to run the basic injection test `aireplay-ng -9 wlan0` in the terminal and I get `command not found` when I try it as admin. The weird thing is it seems to work as root (I didn't try running the test - I just typed in `aireplay-ng` to see if it recognized the command, and it does). I don't think it is a PATH problem, but I added `/usr/sbin/aireplay-ng` to `/root/.bashrc` like this (just incase):

```
PATH=~/usr/sbin/aireplay-ng:$PATH
```

I don't think it is the path, because - as you can see, aireplay-ng is located in `/usr/sbin/` which is already part of my PATH variable (noticeable when I execute `echo $PATH`).

The odd part is - when I log in as root, it seems to work - I didn't actually run the test as root (probably not the best idea), but I did type in `aireplay-ng` to see if the command was recognized, and it was. Not sure if a symlink would help - but I'm not going to try anything until I get a response.

Just trying to get the aireplay-ng command recognized. Thanks in advance. (I posted this on superuser too - but it seems like people are more active on stack).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I think you need root access for aireplay-ng (probably for the whole aircrack-ng suite too).